# Cant figure out views rendering (they are prepended right before /body)

Tags: ember.js

First my apologies: Im very new to ember.js and struggling so far.

I have a pretty basic app written and I've been using this as my main guide: http://trek.github.com/

My biggest issue right now is figuring out how to deal with Views, specifically the rendered HTML and where it appears in the DOM.  It appears, at least with my app currently, the DOM elements are created and inserted into the page but right before /body.  So everything just loads below the footer of my main site design.

Doesnt seem to matter where placement of the script templates are in relation to the page, or anything like that??

Is there a way to render views to an existing container div or something?  Am I thinking about this wrong?  Im used to working with jsRender where I have templates setup, but they typically rendered to an in-memory string that I then needed to insert into an existing container like $('#containerDiv').html(myRenderedHtmlFromATemplate);

Thanks for any help or guidance with this!

Answer (score 3):

Ember will want its views to be hierarchical in the DOM so it can rely on event propagation. You probably noticed a `<div class="ember-application">` that gets injected, and then all of your views are rendered inside of that.

You can specify the [rootElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement) when you create your Application. The application will be created inside that element and leave the rest of the DOM untouched. If you don't specify that `rootElement`, then Ember will insert itself right before `</body>` as you observed.

Example:

```
window.MyApp = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: "#containerDiv"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code it isn't completely clear what exactly is going on, but, I do not see you mention anything about outlets so I assume that might be your problem.

Check out this url on outlets: http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/

Comment: I am using Outlets.  I think the biggest problem is that it seems either A) ember apps are assuming they are the whole page? or B) they dont play well with just being "inserted" into an existing page layout etc.  Or Im just doing something wrong?  IS ember specifically designed to be more for SPA only?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle in your original post of what you have so far for myself and others to look at.

Answer (score 0):

tuxedo25 has the best solution. If you are using `StateManager` you can also use the following:

```
App.StateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
    rootElement: '.content',
    initialState: 'initial',
    initial: Ember.ViewState.create({
        route: 'initial',
        view: Ember.View.create({ templateName: 'initial' })
    })
});
```